# Использование button в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, button

Столкнулся с проблемой, что при передаче command в Button функции, она выполняется до срабатывания даже mainloop. Можно ли как то этого избежать? 
Пример:

```py
def submit(entry):
    a = entry.get()
    if a == 'Enter smth':
        messagebox.showerror('Ошибка', 'Введите число')
        return
    else:
        foo(a)

entry = Entry(main)
entry.insert(0,'Enter smth')

run = Button(main,
             text=" Enter ",
             command=submit(entry)
             )

main.mainloop()
```

mainloop() не выполняется, при обработке command программа сразу переходит в функцию, видит, что в поле введена строка и выводит ошибку, после чего закрывает програму.

Comment: @WindWolf, если ответ вам помог, то отметьте ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто в кнопке надо заменить `command = submit(entry)` на `command = lambda: submit(entry)` и все хорошо запашет.